# function for dataTable with differnt forms of data

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Below is the code snippet:

tansaction.xhtml

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:dataTable value="#{transactionMB.transactionEntryList}" var="transInfo" rowStyleClass="tdDownValue">

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">
    <p:dataTable value="#{transactionMB.loggingList}" var="logInfo" rowStyleClass="tdDownValue">

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form3">
    <p:dataTable value="#{transactionMB.salesEntryList}" var="salesInfo" rowStyleClass="tdDownValue">

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to start long-running initialization of lists  after the page load.

You can try something like:

1. Do not initialize your lists in bean constructor/post construct method. Instead of it, add to the bean public methods, that you will call after page load.

   ```
   public void loadTransactionEntryList();
   public void loadloggingList();
   public void loadSalesEntryList();
   ```
2. Add loading indicators near the table, and remoteCommands to call load* methods. Note, that by default loading indicators are shown and tables are hidden. oncomplete call is used to toggle indicator and table after command finishes.

   ```
   <h:form id="commands-form">
       <p:remoteCommand name="loadTransactionEntryListCommand" action="#{transactionMB.loadTransactionEntryList}" 
                   update=":form1" oncomplete="hideLoadingDisplayTable('#form1');"/>

       <p:remoteCommand name="loadloggingListCommand" action="#{transactionMB.loadloggingList}" 
                   update=":form2" oncomplete="hideLoadingDisplayTable('#form2');"/>

       <p:remoteCommand name="loadSalesEntryListCommand" action="#{transactionMB.loadSalesEntryList}" 
                   update=":form3" oncomplete="hideLoadingDisplayTable('#form3');"/>
   </h:form>

   <h:form id="form1">
       <div class="loading-indicator" style="display: block;">...</div>
       <p:dataTable value="#{transactionMB.transactionEntryList}" var="transInfo" rowStyleClass="tdDownValue" style="display: none;">

   </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>

   <h:form id="form2">
       <div class="loading-indicator" style="display: block;">...</div>
       <p:dataTable value="#{transactionMB.loggingList}" var="logInfo" rowStyleClass="tdDownValue" style="display: none;">

   </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>

   <h:form id="form3">
       <div class="loading-indicator" style="display: block;">...</div>
       <p:dataTable value="#{transactionMB.salesEntryList}" var="salesInfo" rowStyleClass="tdDownValue" style="display: none;">

   </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>
   ```
3. Call commands with JavaScript in the end of the document or with jquery's (document ).ready().

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       loadTransactionEntryListCommand();
       loadloggingListCommand();
       loadSalesEntryListCommand();
   </script>
   ```
4. Finally, implement hideLoadingDisplayTable(formId) function to hide loading indicator and  show table with JavaScript.

Comment: Can you please suggest what i need to write in loadTransactionEntryList method of tansaction managed bean as you have suggested(transactionMB.loadTransactionEntryList) in search.xhtml. Thanks.@BlindNW.

Comment: You need to initialize (fill) the transactionMB.transactionEntryList property in this method. Load values of this list from DB, or wherever you load it from.

Comment: i was trying to do as you mentioned, but could not able to implement hideLoadingDisplayTable(formId) as i could not able to get the div property in "hideLoadingDisplayTable" to show or hide dataTable.Please suggest. @BlindNW

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use pagination with lazy loading in your data tables. Only first page of data will be loaded when your XHTML page is loaded, which should certainly reduce your load time.

Extend `LazyDataModel` and implement `load(...)` methods to lazy load your data in tables.

Initiate your database connections, and create your custom lazyDataModel objects in a method of your backing bean which is annotated with `@postConstruct`. Maintain current page and page size in your lazyDatalModel. In load(...) method get the next page from the database and return.

These are few links to help you.

Primefaces datatable paginationand lazy loading, see primefaces showcase -
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

JDBC pagination -
http://java.avdiel.com/Tutorials/JDBCPaging.html

If you are using Persistance (JPA or Hibernate ), see for setFirstResult() and setMaxResult() methods of Query object.

Comment: I cannot do pagination for different forms in a page. Users should be able to see different forms like transaction form, sales form, entry form etc in the same page. and issue is if transaction form has many records to load and other two forms has few records, page wont load until all forms has completed loading data from database. I want to avoid that and show which ever form is loading and other form may show progress bar in that section stating its loading -- @Amit P.

Comment: I got your idea, that your tables are like sub frames in a page, page should be loaded immediately, if there is a dely loading content of subframes a progress indicator should be visible. But still I want to ask 1. Is there any specific reason for not able to do pagination, 2. As you told some tables may have more records, If this number is big then certainly you should not load everything in one go, you may face out of memory situation.